# TypeError: customerFactory.getOrders is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

It's my third learning AngularJS and I'm struggling. I need help. I keep getting `TypeError: customerFactory.getOrders is not a function` I have checked for typos several times but can't find any.

### customersController.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('CustomersController', function ($scope, $log, customerFactory, appSettings) { 
    'use strict';

    $scope.sortBy = 'name';
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.customers = [];
    $scope.appSettings = appSettings; 

    function init (){
        customerFactory.getCustomers()
            .success(function(customers) {
                $scope.customers = customers;
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                //error handler
                $log.log(data.error + ' ' + status);
            });
    }

    init();

    $scope.doSort = function (propName) {
        $scope.sortBy = propName;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

### allorders.html

```
<h3>Customer Orders</h3>
<br/>
Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="orderFilter.product" />
<br/><br/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="order in orders | filter:orderFilter | orderBy:'name'">
        <td>{{ order.product }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.total | currency:'PLN' }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-class="totalType">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>{{ ordersTotal | currency:'PLN' }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### allOrderscontroller.js

```
(function() {

    var AllOrdersController = function ($scope, customerFactory) {
    $scope.orders = null;
    $scope.ordersTotal = 0.0;
    $scope.totalType;

    function init() {
        customerFactory.getOrders()
            .success(function(orders) {
                $scope.orders = orders;
                getOrdersTotal();
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                //handle error
        });
    }

    function getOrdersTotal() {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0, len = $scope.orders.length; i < len; i++) {
            total += $scope.orders[i].total;
        }
        $scope.ordersTotal = total;
        $scope.totalType = ($scope.ordersTotal > 100) ? 'success' : 'danger';
    }

    init();
    };


    AllOrdersController.$inject = ['$scope', 'customerFactory'];

        angular.module('myApp')
            .controller('AllOrdersController', AllOrdersController);
}());
```

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/app.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/customersController.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/ordersController.js"></script>
        <script src="app/services/customersFactory.js"></script>
        <script src="app/services/values.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/allOrdersController.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#/customers">Customers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/orders">Orders</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </header>
        <div ng-view></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

I'm only trying to display `allorders.html`'s content.

Console

```
TypeError: customerFactory.getOrders is not a function
    at init (http://localhost:3000/app/controllers/allOrdersController.js:9:19)
    at new AllOrdersController (http://localhost:3000/app/controllers/allOrdersController.js:28:2)
    at invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:4473:17)
    at Object.instantiate (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:4481:27)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:9108:28
    at link (http://localhost:3000/angular-route.js:977:26)
    at invokeLinkFn (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:8746:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:8246:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:7637:13)
    at publicLinkFn (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:7512:30) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Please help if anyone can. Almost been sitting by days for the whole day :(.

[image]

EDIT

### customersFactory.js

```
(function() {
    var customerFactory = function($http) {

            var factory = {};

            factory.getCustomers = function() {
               return $http.get('/customers');
            };

            factory.getCustomer = function(customerId) {
                return $http.get('/customers/' + customerId);
            };

            factory.getOrders = function() {
                return $http.get('/orders');
            }

            return factory;

    };
            customerFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
            angular.module('myApp').factory('customerFactory', customerFactory);
}());
```

I tried to write an orders route in `server.js` like so:

```
app.route('/orders')
    .get(function(req, res)) {
      var orders = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = customers.length; i < len; i++) {
          orders += customers[i][orders];
        }
        return orders;
    }
})
```

I am trying to collect all orders from the `customers` array in `server.js`. No progress. What am I doing wrong? This is my

### server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

/* EXPRESS 3.0
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/'));
});
*/

// EXPRESS 4.0
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if ('development' == env) {
   // configure stuff here
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
}

/*EXPRESS 3.0
app.get('/customers/:id', function(req, res) {
    var customerId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    var data = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = customers.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (customers[i].id === customerId) {
            data = customer[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    res.json(data)
});
*/

//EXPRESS 4.0
app.route('/customers/:id')
    .get(function(req, res) {
    var customerId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    var data = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = customers.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (customers[i].id === customerId) {
            data = customers[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    res.json(data)
    })

/* EXPRESS 3.0
app.get('/customers', function(req, res) {
    res.json(customers);
});
*/

//EXPRESS 4.0
app.route('/customers')
    .get (function(req, res) {
    return res.json(customers);
})

app.route('/orders')
    .get(function(req, res)) {
      var orders = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = customers.length; i < len; i++) {
          orders += customers[i][orders];
        }
        return orders;
    }
})

app.listen(3000);

console.log('Express listening on port 3000');


var customers = [
    { 
            id: 1,
            joined: '2005-09-07', 
            name: 'Mayweather', 
            city: 'Brooklyn', 
            orderTotal: '43.1299',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Pencils',
                total: 9.9956
              }
            ]

          }, 
          {
            id: 2,
            joined: '2005-09-07', 
            name: 'Jason', 
            city: 'Cleveland', 
            orderTotal: '89.8933',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'iPad',
                total: 20.9956
              }
            ]  
          }, 
          {
            id: 3,
            joined: '1999-08-27', 
            name: 'Jade', 
            city: 'Wroclaw', 
            orderTotal: '77.0092',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Pillows',
                total: 12.2311
              }
            ]
          }, 
          {
            id: 4,
            joined: '2015-09-01', 
            name: 'David', 
            city: 'Accra', 
            orderTotal: '13.8465',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Serek',
                total: 11.4782
              }
            ]
          }, 
          {
            id: 5,
            joined: '2001-01-18', 
            name: 'Doyet',
            city: 'Paris',
            orderTotal: '23.9930',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Serek',
                total: 11.4782
              }
            ]
          }];
```

Comment: What is the definition of `customerFactory` ?

Comment: I can see you are using ng-view, can you share the route configuration code in `app.js`, and also share the code of `customerFactory` as well. Based on what you have post right now, I am thinking you are using `customerFactorty` as a service to call some API and probably it doesn't return you a object yet.

Comment: i added `customerFactory` in an EDIT @PSL

Comment: So it is now evident that you have not defined getOrders function in the factory and hence the error

Comment: @ShaohaoLin I added `app.js`

Comment: `factory.getCustomers = function() {
               return $http.get('/customers');
            };` Do you understand how this work first?

Comment: yes i already added this just now. but then i get `404 not found` which means I probably have to create a route for it in the `server.js`?

Comment: Can you update `factory` code? And yes you should create a route in your backend `server.js` as well.

Comment: try add the code `factory.getOrders = function(customerId) {return $http.get('/orders/' + customerId); };`

Comment: That should work. Let me know if still have problem!

Comment: i fixed it already @ShaohaoLin. thank you very very much. i had to define a functions getOrders, create a route :)

Comment: @ShaohaoLin now i need to learn how to attach a database like mongodb to my application so people can add themselves and orders. will mongodb be the best db for angularjs? what do you think?

Comment: @siaw23 Yeah `mongodb` will be fine. Or you can try `firebase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, looking at your `customerFactory` there is no `getOrders` function to call yet hence why the error is triggered when making a call to this from the `init` function within your `allOrdersController`.

Comment: i get that part. it's funny how the tutorial i'm following that define `getOrders` but still gets the app to work. if i define `getOrders` that will me i have to define a route for it too right?

Comment: @siaw23 it depends. If you are calling an API with some parameters like `customerID=1`,  and return data for you. Then you have to create a backend route which will listen this uri and return the data for you.

Comment: @ShaohaoLin I have tried to add a route can you please check if i'm doing the right thing?